# Given T on m edges, Prove that T is a subgraph of G.

Tags: graph-theory

Let T be a tree with m edges, and let G be an n-vertex graph with more than
$n(m − 1) − {m\choose 2}$ edges. Prove that T is a subgraph of G.

It seems clear that the question is missing a bit of information its clear that $n\geq m+1 $

The problem i am having is lets assume that $n=m+1$ then we have $(m+1)(m-1)-(m^2 -m) = m^2-m +m -1 -m^2+m=m-1$ now it does say more than so i guess you could argue that G has m edges but its clear that the statement isn't true in this case just pick G to be any tree that is not T and the result follows.

Any idea what this is actually saying?

Edit: NVM $m=1$ is ok because it says that G has more than 0 edges ie it has at least 1 edge. That is it says $|E(G)|> n(m-1)- {m \choose 2} $

Assume the statement for some $m\geq1$. Let $G$ be a graph with $|E|> (m+2)((m+1) − 1) − {m+1 \choose 2}$ and $T$ a tree with $m+1$ edges. The degree of any vertex in $G$ is at most $|V|-1$, so if $G'$ is a subgraph of $G$ obtained by removing a vertex, 
$$|E'|> (m+2)((m+1) − 1) − {m+1 \choose 2}-((m+2)-1)$$
$$|E'|> m(m+2) - {m+1 \choose 2} -m-1 $$ we WTS that 
$$|E'|> m^2-1 +m - {m+1 \choose 2} \geq (m+1)(m-1) - {m\choose 2} $$
$$ m - {m+1 \choose 2} \geq  - {m\choose 2} $$
$$0\geq 0 $$

Therefore if $T'$ is a subgraph of $T$ obtained by removing an edge, there is a subgraph $S'$ of $G'$ with $S'\cong T'$. Since the vertex removed from $G$ was arbitrary, it follows that there is a subgraph of $G$ congruent to $T$.

Comment: At first I assumed it meant that there was a subgraph of $G$ that was isomorphic to $T$, but that isn't true when $m=1$.  I'd check in with whoever asked you this question, because it seems pretty sketchy to me.

Comment: You lost me at line 5. On line 1 you say that $|E|\gt n(m-1)-\binom m2$ so that $|E|\gt(m+1)(m-1)-\binom m2=(m+2)(m-1)/2$ assuming $n=m+1$. Where does $(m+1)(m-1)-(m^2-m)$ come from?

Comment: @bof m choose 2 is equivalent to $m^2-m$

Comment: No, "$m$ choose $2$" = $\binom m2=\frac{m(m-1)}2=\frac{m^2-m}2$. In general, $$\binom mk=\frac{m(m-1)\cdots(m-k+1)}{k!}.$$